# Italic inline citation in CSL + Pandoc

Tags: pandoc, citations, csl

I am using the CSL style under http://www.zotero.org/styles/chicago-author-date with Pandoc. I would like to have the authors' names in italics style when citing them in text. How can I achieve this? Thank you for your help.

EDIT: To be more precise, I would like to have in-line citations without parentesis, like 
*Fisman* (2001). I have tried to add `font-style="italic"` to `<text macro="contributors-short"/>`, but it only works when using parenthesis-style citations with `[@Fisman2001]`. A minimal working example is provided [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2nOIt8ZEYHcNTN6R3NoWXdwNlE/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to modify the CSL style. There are various ways of getting what you want, but likely the easies is to modify [line 513](https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/chicago-author-date.csl#L513) of the style from

`<text macro="contributors-short"/>`

to

`<text macro="contributors-short" font-style="italic"/>`

See e.g. [here](https://www.zotero.org/support/dev/citation_styles/style_editing_step-by-step#manually_editing_csl_styles) for some general instructions on editing CSL styles, though you basically just edit the file in a text editor.

Comment: I tried this also before but for some reason it does not work for me. I have put together an example that - on my machine - reproduces the error, packed to a .zip file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2nOIt8ZEYHcNTN6R3NoWXdwNlE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: OK. It'd be helpful to provide more details in your question in the first place - e.g. what you've tried already, example output etc. Specifically, the solution above works for ```[@Fisman2001]``` which produces (_Fisman_ 2001). That's the only thing you can actually control via CSL. I'd assume that pandoc-citeproc decided not to apply any styling on authors outside of parentheses, which in general is probably a reasonable decision. You can, of course, do \_Fisman\_ [-@Fisman2001] to get _Fisman_ (2001)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions - I have updated my question. It would be a pity if I could not control citations without parenthesis with CSL... Unfortunately, your last suggestion only works in this simple case. It is too cumbersome to use when having multiple authors and trying to adhere to the general formatting specified in the CSL.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I'm pretty sure that's not possible. Setting the italics on cs:name directly doesn't work, either. I'd assume this is a conscious decision on the part of the pandoc-citeproc devs, though you can certainly ask them. CSL doesn't specify the format for authors outside of parentheses, so there is no right or wrong way to implement this.